# PyEphem Ephemeride Calculation Uncertainties

Tags: pyephem

I'm using PyEphem to calculate the future position of the Moon to high accuracy and am interested in quantifying the uncertainties and returning them as part of my script. Is there functionality within PyEphem to return uncertainties for body positions or do I need to calculate them myself?

I'm considering the position of the moon in J2000 RA and DEC and am trying to get lunar positions from the current time to 1 month in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that a library like Skyfield will give you much higher accuracy than PyEphem, though it also does not provide error bars — you'd need to read up on the expected error in the ephemeris (like DE421) you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, no — PyEphem does not provide any data about uncertainty. The best you could do would be to consult the source code to find what algorithm it uses (VSOP87, I think?) and then look up the uncertainties of that in the literature.

Comment: Thanks Brandon! I've tried JPL NAIF's SPICE tool but it doesn't have the functionality to propagate uncertainties either.